# How to visualize specific object keys in pug?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pug

from this request:

```
router.get('/weather', function(req, res, next) {

  requestify.get('https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city=Trenton,TN&key=myKey').then(function(response) {
    // Get the response body (JSON parsed - JSON response or jQuery object in case of XML response)
    console.log(response.getBody());

    
    res.render('weather', {
      message: (response.body)
    })
  });
```

I'm getting this JSON:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      rh: 94,
      pod: 'n',
      lon: -88.94145,
      pres: 998.7,
      country_code: 'US',
      clouds: 25,
      ts: 1596444360,
      solar_rad: 0,
      state_code: 'TN',
      city_name: 'Trenton',
      wind_spd: 1.54,
      wind_cdir_full: 'east-southeast',
      wind_cdir: 'ESE',
      slp: 1012.4,
      vis: 5,
      lat: 35.98062,
      temp: 18.9,
      station: 'F5468',
      elev_angle: -22.32,
      app_temp: 19.3
    }
  ],
  count: 1
}
```

Opening my browser and going to  `http://localhost:3000/weather` the resulting JSON is correctly visualized. However, I would like to visualize only only lat / long and temp by using pug.

Here my pug code:

```
html
  head
    title= Weather
  body
    h1= message
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it all in `h1` string you could do:

```
html
  head
    title= Weather
  body
    h1= `${message.lon}, ${message.lat}, ${message.temp}` // or any other way you'd concat strings in javascript.
```

OR

```js
html
  head
    title= Weather
  body
    h1= message.lon
    h1= message.lat
    h1= message.temp
```

you can also send partial data from your route:

```js
res.render('weather', {
  message: {let: response.body.let, lon: response.body.lon, temp: response.body.temp}
});
```

This is all considering you really are sending a parsed object otherwise you'd have to parse it somewhere along the road with `JSON.parse()`